# Async Task to Youtube

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, youtube, async-await

I'm new to this actually. I have short application just to check whether the application can get the authentication asynchronously from youtube and return the application back to it's track. Here are the snippet of my code

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await YoutubeAuth();

    MessageBox.Show(token);
}

private async Task YoutubeAuth()
{
    OAUth2Credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        new ClientSecrets { ClientId = YoutubeClientId, ClientSecret = YoutubeClientSecret },
        // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
        // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
        new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None
    );

    token = OAUth2Credential.Token.TokenType;
}
```

The code `MessageBox.Show(token);` never been executed.

---

**EDIT:**

I have tried other simpler code like below and still the MessageBox is never triggered

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await YoutubeAuth();

    MessageBox.Show(token);
}

private async Task YoutubeAuth()
{
    token = "test token";
}
```

Comment: Perhaps an exception is thrown from `YoutubeAuth()`? Have you tried debugging the code?

Comment: I have debugged the code and make sure there is no exception threw from the code

Comment: Are you sure? Did you turn CLR exceptions on?

Comment: @Yuval: I already installed this Exception Breaker tool (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/50091e25-9e75-40d3-9780-a05892f474de) and still no exception coming and the message box is not triggered

Comment: And you're invoking `button1_Click()` from the UI i assume, right?

Comment: Yes i click the button1 from the UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems interesting. I have written fastly WPF example app to verify

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestAsyncTaskToYoutube.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestAsyncTaskToYoutube"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestAsyncTaskToYoutube
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private string token;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button.Click += button_Click;
        }

        private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await YoutubeAuth();
            MessageBox.Show(token);
        }

        private Task<int> YoutubeAuth()
        {
            token = "test token";
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
}
```

No problems here. MessageButton fires as it should be. I am sure your code is a bit different from mine anywhere :|

How can we help You?

EDIT: Avoiding Task.FromResult() (.NET 4.5 feature)

```
private async Task YoutubeAuth()
{
    token = "test token";
}
```

Comment: I still using .Net framework 4.0. `Task.FromResult(0)` is available on .Net Framework 4.5 above.

Comment: The code is the same like mine. What visual studio do you use? I use Visual Studio 2010 and implement async await using "Microsoft Visual Studio Async CTP" (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9983)

Comment: I have tested it using Visual Studio 2012 Professional and Visual Studio 2013 Community. I am not using "Microsoft Visual Studio Async CTP" - everything i need is already build-in

Answer (score 1):

My *guess* is that you have created a button called `button1` and then you wrote a method called `button1_Click`, but you never linked the two together.

In the common .Net UI frameworks (Winforms, WPF), that won't work, because the name of the method does not actually matter. What matters is that the button is set to invoke the method on click. How exactly to do this depends on the UI, but I believe double clicking on the button in the designer should create method that will be invoked on click for you.

Comment: I created the method by double clicking the button